# Functions of WKExtensionDelegate are not called for watchOS

Tags: swift, watchos

This is my `WatchDelegate.swift`:

```
import WatchKit

class WatchDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        print("FINISHED LAUNCHING>>>>>>>>>>>") //not called
    }
}
```

My `info.plist`:

[image]

My app is launching on my watch, but above delegate method is not called. Why?

Comment: Are you defining your app entry point with SwiftUI, i.e. `@main struct Foo: App`? In this case, the docs say that you should use the `onChange` modifier to listen for lifecycle events. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/1628241-applicationdidfinishlaunching)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am facing the same issue and not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't add anything to `info.plist`, I just added some [magic swift sprinkles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/wkextensiondelegateadaptor):

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WatchApp: App {
    
    // 
    @WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var delegate: ExtensionDelegate
    //     
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
// etc
```

I then see logging from

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        // stuff logged here shows in console
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a problem uploading my app to App Store. I got an error: Invalid Info.plist key. The key 'WKExtensionDelegateClassName' in bundle....  I removed the key from info.plist and the upload went through. It just works even though I do not know why. I do have the same magic swift sprinkles as you do.

Comment: I get this error when I add the line that you suggested: "@WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor should only be used within an extension based process"